# JInternalFrame custom on-screen keyboard

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I'm trying to create an on-screen keyboard using JInternalFrame, but I'm having an obvious problem. Whenever I click a button on JInternalFrame I lose focus on the text field from the main window (a custom Component). Can I somehow prevent JInternalFrame from gaining the focus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to create an on-screen keyboard using JInternalFrame,

Don't use a JInternalFrame.

Instead use a non modal JDialog. Then you can use:

```
dialog.setFocusableWindowState(false);
```

to prevent the dialog from gaining focus.

Comment: To instantiate JDialog, for first parameter I had to get owner Form object. I got it using getTopLevelAncestor() on my custom JComponent owner window.